# Moving log location for Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, systemd, syslog, tomcat, rsyslog

On a fresh instance in AWS of Ubuntu 18.04, I have installed tomcat9 through apt.  I'm replacing a 14.04 Ubuntu install where i was running tomcat7. Due to the nature of my application, I have a very large disk mounted under /data/ebs1.  On this disk I have set-up a folder to house a very large set of tomcat logs.

```
/data/ebs1/tomcat-logs
```

Getting logging moved here is giving me a headache.  It seems that tomcat9 is set up to log to syslog.  So bear with me as I try to go down the rabbit hole of configurations here.

Here's my **/etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service**

```
#
# Systemd unit file for Apache Tomcat
#

[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat 9 Web Application Server
Documentation=https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html
After=network.target

[Service]

# Configuration
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat9"
Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat9"
Environment="CATALINA_TMPDIR=/tmp"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/tomcat9

# Lifecycle
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=+/usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-update-policy.sh
ExecStart=/bin/sh /usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-start.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=on-abort

# Logging
SyslogIdentifier=tomcat9

# Security
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
PrivateTmp=yes
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
NoNewPrivileges=true
LogsDirectory=tomcat9
LogsDirectoryMode=750
CacheDirectory=tomcat9
CacheDirectoryMode=750
ProtectSystem=strict
ReadWritePaths=/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/
ReadWritePaths=/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/
ReadWritePaths=/data/ebs1/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The only thing I changed here was i added `data/ebs1/` to the list of ReadWritePaths.
This file outlines a SyslogIdentifier of `tomcat9`.

And there's a custom handler set up for tomcat9 in **/etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat9.conf**

```
# Send Tomcat messages to catalina.out when using systemd
$template TomcatFormat,"[%timegenerated:::date-year%-%timegenerated:::date-month%-%timegenerated:::date-day% %timegenerated:::date-hour%:%timegenerated:::date-minute%:%timegenerated:::date-second%] [%syslogseverity-text%]%msg%\n"

:programname, startswith, "tomcat9" {
  /data/ebs1/tomcat-logs/catalina.out;TomcatFormat
  stop
}
```

I changed this from /var/log/tomcat9 to /data/ebs1/tomcat-logs.

So now when I go to look inside /data/ebs1/tomcat-logs, I see catalina datestamped log files like `catalina.2020-03-25.log` But no catalina.out.  And the catalina datestamped log file doesn't contain everything.  So some of the logging is going there, some of the logging is still going to syslog.  I was hoping to get ALL logging to go to my catalina.out.  I can't even figure out who is responsible for creating the datestamped catalina files.  Syslog?  Tomcat?  My worries is that if my logs are still going to /var/log/syslog i'm going to fill up my disk quickly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Ok so turns out the configs I posted were in fact, correct. But I had a few things going wrong for me.
`journalctl -u rsyslog` revealed that rsyslog didn't have write permissions to the new catalina.out.  `adm` was the group on the folder (and luckily syslog was in that group too).  Adding group-write permissions solved that.

So I was still getting output in /var/log/syslog even though /etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat9.conf had a "stop" in it.  What I didn't realize is that /etc/rsyslog.conf loads config files from /etc/rsyslog.d/ in **name** order.  The contents of /etc/rsyslog.d/ were like this:

```
20-ufw.conf
21-cloudinit.conf
50-default.conf
tomcat9.conf
```

I just renamed the file to come before "default" and everything was happy.  No more logs in /var/log/syslog!

```
20-ufw.conf
21-cloudinit.conf
30-tomcat9.conf
50-default.conf
```

Anyway.  High-five-self.

Comment: I tried your way,And then I executed command "systemctl daemon-reload", "systemctl restart rsyslog", and "systemctl restart tomcat9".   But catalina.out still does not appear in /var/log/tomcat9. I use ubuntu server 18.04.5 LTS and tomat9 (installed with apt). Any other suggestion?